# jquery slider toggle animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to get my slider to work. I know how I could make one, but i am trying to use `toggle()`.. it has proven to be quite difficult, does anyone know anything i dont?

http://jsfiddle.net/kr2wE/

```
$("#slider").on("click", function () {
    $("#slider").toggle(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            "height":"100px"
        }, 1000);
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            "height":"0"
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#slider").toggle(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        "height":"100px"
    }, 1000);
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        "height":"20px"
    }, 1000);
});
```

The correct version of this form is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/f4bAK/)

Note: This function was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in 1.9 https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/. So I would strongly advise you not to use it.

Comment: brilliant thanks. can you explain why `toggle` wasn't working?

Comment: Toggle allready registers click event inside the .toggle function call.